# Evernote SDK for desktop (not web) applications. User and Pass instead of token

Tags: evernote

Does anyone knows: is this a possibility to use User's email and password instead of token (even tokens are not available for production).
I have an desktop application which should work like the webclipper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use email and password, you will need to implement [OAuth](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/authentication.php). For the developer token, you can request enabling it for your production account by [submitting a support ticket](https://www.evernote.com/SupportLogin.action).

Answer (score 0):

@kentaro is right. If you want your application to work with multiple user accounts, you must implement authentication using OAuth. The direct sign in using username/password is restricted to Evernote's own applications.

You can also ask your users to provide their personal developer API tokens. Each user will have to request the token individually. In this case you won't need to deal with the authentication flow.

Also, if you're having a specific desktop platform in mind and your intent is only to create notes, you may also want to look at local interaction with the [Mac](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/applescript.php) or [Windows](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/enscript.php) client. With these options you also won't need to think about authentication at all.